# How to reference object from scala high order method

Tags: scala

I'm wondering is there a way to access the object which a high order method is called from in scala. For example say I have the following code:

```
val list = List(1, 3, 4, -1, 2, 0)
val filtered = list filter(_ > 0)
```

Say within the filter method I wanted to test the head value how would I achieve it? Something like:

```
val filter = list filter(_ > 0 + head)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always pass the result of getList to a function e.g.:

```
scala> def getList: List[Int] = (0 to 10).toList
getList: List[Int]

scala> getList match { case (xs: List[Int]) =>
     |   xs.filter(_ > xs.head + 5)
     | }
res1: List[Int] = List(6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

or something slightly more interesting than `x > 5`:

```
scala> def getList: List[Int] = (10 to 1 by -1).toList
getList: List[Int]

scala> getList
res6: List[Int] = List(10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)

scala> getList match { case (xs: List[Int]) =>
     |   xs.filter{ x => xs.head % x == 0 }
     | }
res7: List[Int] = List(10, 5, 2, 1)
```

**Note**: This works fine for `xs.head`, since it should be a pretty cheap operation, but if you plan looking further down into the list, like xs(5) or something, you would be traversing the list many many times.

Answer (score 8):

You access it the same way you did when you accessed `filter`:

```
val filter = list filter(_ > 0 + list.head)
```

I should mention that since `List` is immutable, you can do this safely.

If you are chaining multiple operations on the list, then the simplest solution is to create an intermediate `val`:

```
val first10 = x.getList() take 10
val filter = first10 filter(_ > 0 + first10.head)
```

As much as I love chaining operations together, this can often be more readable anyway.

Comment: Just realised my problem is slightly more complicated as the access I need is in a chain of operations and the list is initially returned by a call I want to avoid making a second time. So its something more like: `val filterd = x.getList() take 10 filter(_ > 0)  // how to avoid calling x.getList() a second time to get the head?`

Comment: Updated per your comment